# How do I use MySQL 5.1's RLIKE with a regular expression containing a backslash?

Tags: mysql

I need select rows with the word "foo" (i.e. `str =~ /\b(foo)\b/`). This doesn't seem to work in MySQL 5.1:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM foo WHERE keyword RLIKE '\bbar\b' LIMIT 10;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM foo WHERE keyword RLIKE 'bar' LIMIT 10;
+------+-----------------------+
| id   | keyword               |
+------+-----------------------+
| 1220 | foo bar               |
| 1221 | foo                   |
| 1222 | foobar                |
| 1223 | afoo bar              |
| 1224 | foo barf              |
| 1225 | foo bar baz           |
| 1226 | food bar              |
| 1227 | fool bar              |
| 1228 | football              |
| 1229 | the game is afoot     |
+------+-----------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've tried `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE keyword RLIKE '\\bbar\\b' LIMIT 10` as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql does not support the `\b` regexp code. However, they have another way to do it.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE keyword RLIKE '[[:<:]]bar[[:>:]]' LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

try using REGEXP it's really nice and better than rlike by a mile

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html, it states that all backslashes need to be done twice. eg

```
\\bfoo\\b
```

should work

Comment: I'm not trying to match a literal '\b', I'm trying to match a word boundary. I'll update the question to be more explicit about this.

Comment: No, I know but thats exactly what the manual says you would need to do.

Comment: My question did state that I tried `\\b`, and the manual was obviously talking about when you want to match a literal backslash in a regex. You obviously didn't try it out for yourself, and your answer is wrong, so my downvote stands.

Comment: No, you stated you tried \\bfoo\b - the last one missing a second \. I dont have 5.1 to hand to try it on, and Im not upgrading a test box for you.

Comment: Quoth I from my original question: "I've tried SELECT * FROM foo WHERE keyword RLIKE '\\bbar\\b' LIMIT 10 as well." WRT to testing, RLIKE [has been around for a long time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/regexp.html). So it boils down to you reading the manual, then not bothering to test your answer, which was wrong. Not helpful!

Answer (score -2):

You can use REGEXP http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Comment: REGEXP is just a synonym for RLIKE, and thus does not solve my problem.